# mysql join query with multiple AND condition

Tags: mysql

i dont know why my sql query doesn't work

TABLE users

```
userid   firstname    lastname
1         JOHN         DEO
2         JANE         DEO
```

TABLE msg

```
msg_id  msg_from   msg_to     received  age  city  country    product  weight  price     timestamp            
1       userid(1)  userid(2)  null      26   any   any         rice     25     $100      2018-10-04 14:37:12
```

My query:

```
SELECT SND.userid, SND.firstname, SND.lastname, M.age, M.city, M.country
FROM msg as M
JOIN users as SND 
ON SND.userid = M.msg_from
WHERE M.msg_to = 'userid 1' AND product = 'rice' AND price >='$100'
```

i dont see any problem but cant get results

Comment: age? What is age?

Comment: M.msg_to = 'userid 1' - you don't have any in the data.

Comment: @Strawberry yes age. its like that. and thats how i want it to be

Comment: First of all `msg_to` is an integer I suppose so you should have `msg_to = 1` and I am not sure how the comparison will work for price when you have a dollar sign in it. Why isn’t price a number?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks. there is no problem i can remove dollar sign. i appreciate if you give me example

Comment: Your code suggests that you are only interested in messages sent by user id 1 to user id 1. in other words the on clause will find user id1 but the where clause will filter on user id 1.

Comment: @mikejoe, any feedback on the answers given?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that userid/msg_to/msg_from is an integer and price in msg table is a number I would change the WHERE clause to

```
WHERE M.msg_to = 1 AND product = 'rice' AND price >= 100.0
```

And if they are strings then you could do

```
WHERE M.msg_to = '1' AND product = 'rice' AND CAST(price AS DECIMAL(10,2)) >= 100.0
```

assuming you drop the dollar sign.

Comment: Will work if changed  m.msg_to = 2 - on clause has already selected on m.msg_from.

Comment: @P.Salmon Thanks. I didn’t noticed that first and then assumed `msg` contained more rows and that the one in the question was just an example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want get result then take below query

```
SELECT SND.userid, SND.firstname, SND.lastname, M.age, M.city, M.country
FROM msg as M
JOIN users as SND 
ON SND.userid = M.msg_from
WHERE M.msg_to = 'userid 2' AND product = 'rice' AND price >='$100'
```

In your code result not show because userid not match with msg_to column as per your table view